# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 after debugging the app

Tags: android, debugging, flutter

Today I started to run and debug my app after a week and got some errors. I serached on web found some solution on GitHub but they didn't help me a lot.
Here is what I am getting-

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-e7b69ced2e2408da86261227a04f09e0c0fe905d.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :firebase_auth
         project :app > project :cloud_firestore
         project :app > project :google_sign_in
         project :app > project :firebase_core
         project :app > project :firebase_storage
```

and so on...
and here is flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.13.1-pre.59, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.476], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.13.1-pre.59 at C:\Users\acer\flutter
    • Framework revision e58dc16d7b (35 hours ago), 2019-12-06 18:21:52 -0800
    • Engine revision e7b69ced2e
    • Dart version 2.7.0 (build 2.7.0-dev.2.1 a9c77229c2)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)        
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 41.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
```

I tried the solution mentioned here- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30573

Here is my pubspec.yaml dependencies-

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  firebase_core: 0.4.2+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
  provider: ^3.1.0+1
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.0.0"
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.14
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.8
```

Comment: What are your pubspec dependencies?

Comment: Have you followed all of these steps? https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: Yes, I have followed it and found the error one dependency was not updated. Thank you.

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it so others who are facing the issue can find an answer.

Comment: Okay sure I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the steps in from here- [firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup](http://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

The issue here was Analytics wasn't enabled in my pubspec.yaml file.

```
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
```

Thanks to @Benjamin S.